# how to get cross-domain json by javascript

Tags: javascript, json, cross-domain

Is there any way to do this in javascript?

```php
<?
    $fgc=file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=PL&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20AWP%20|%20Worm%20God%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29');
    $json=json_decode($fgc,true);
    echo $json['lowest_price'];
?>
```

Comment: Not without modifying the server to either allow cross-origin requests or to switch to `jsonp`. But then, I'm guessing you're not a Steam developer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible.
steamcommunity.com either has to support jsonp (which it does not) or set the right headers to allow CORS (which it does not).

Your only option is to have a proxy in i.e. PHP that passes the data, but there is most likely a reason that steamcommunity.com haven't implemented these features, and you might be breaking their copyright.